# nn.Parameter() doesn't register as a model parameter with torch.randn()

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to create a module, which contains certain layers of nn.Parameters().
If I initialize the layer as following -

```
self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4,4), requires_grad=True).double()
```

then this layer doesn't appear to register in the module parameters.

However, this initialization does work -

```
self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(4,4), requires_grad=True)
```

Full example -

```
class TestNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNet, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4,4), requires_grad=True).double()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.matmul(x, self.W.T)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x

tnet = TestNet()
print(list(tnet.parameters())) 
### Output = [] (an empty list)
```

Compared to -

```
class TestNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNet, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(4,4), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.matmul(x, self.W.T)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x

tnet = TestNet()
print(list(tnet.parameters()))
```

Which prints -

```
[Parameter containing:
 tensor([[-1.8859e+26,  6.0240e-01,  1.0842e-19,  3.8177e-05],
         [ 1.5229e-27, -8.5899e+09,  1.5226e-27, -3.6893e+19],
         [ 4.2039e-45, -4.6566e-10,  1.5229e-27, -2.0000e+00],
         [ 2.8026e-45,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  4.5918e-40]],
        requires_grad=True)]
```

So what is the difference? Why doesn't the torch.randn() version work?
I couldn't find anything about this in the docs or in previous answers online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `randn` is completely fine. The issue is that `.double()` is being called at the end of the operation:

```
class TestNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNet, self).__init__()
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4,4, dtype = torch.double), requires_grad=True)
        # self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(4,4).double(), requires_grad=True) # also works

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.matmul(x, self.W.T)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x

tnet = TestNet()
print(tnet.W.dtype)
# torch.float64

print(list(tnet.parameters())) 
# [Parameter containing:
# tensor([[-1.9645, -1.5445,  0.2435,  0.4380],
#         [ 1.1403,  0.8836,  0.1811, -0.1212],
#         [ 1.5983, -0.1854, -0.2626,  0.2881],
#         [-1.2364, -0.4802, -0.6038,  0.1164]], requires_grad=True)]
```

Now the code registers the parameters. I added `dtype = torch.double` in the initialization of `randn` to make sure that `self.W` contains `doubles` as before.

---

In summary, we cannot call `nn.Parameter`, and then register its conversion to another data type as our neural network weights for the deep learning system.